# Can we use Arduino mini in eagle to create new custom modal

Tags: arduino-nano, arduino-mini, pcb-design

I want to learn pcb design in Eagle/Fritzing. So i was thinking of using existing amazing Arduino mini/nano in eagle and create a custom pcb which has all arduino capability and plus some components like 7 segment/Bluetooth radio etc.

Can we do that? Is is allowed or arduino design is not open to be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ#toc8:

> I want to design my own board, what should I do?
>
> The reference designs for the Arduino boards are available from their specific product pages. They're licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license, so you are free to use and adapt them for your own needs without asking permission or paying a fee.

You can find the board design files on the **Documentation** tab of each product page.

Arduino Mini product page:
https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mini-05

Arduino Nano product page:
https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano

Answer (score 0):

Arduino is open-source hardware. The Arduino website has [schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino-Pro-Mini-schematic.pdf) and [board layout files](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-pro-mini-reference-design.zip).